# RobotFramework: XPATH exists but not found when click link used

Tags: xpath, robotframework

This one is bugging me. The same xpath is waited for and found. Then i attempt to click it and get an error. Code as below

```
Wait Until Element Is visible  xpath=//*[@id="content"]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/h3/a/i[1]
Click Link  xpath=//*[@id="content"]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/h3/a/i[1]
```

Error here

```
ValueError: Element locator 'xpath=//*[@id="content"]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/h3/a/i[1]' did not match any elements.
```

I know for sure by going in manually that the xpath is there. Something funny about the way Robot does this perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click link will actually look for a link attribute (a=) but your locator is not an 'a' attribute.

Try 'Click Element' instead of 'Click Link'